# Mui IconButton not focusing when adding class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

How can I get an Mui IconButton to show the focusVisible styling similar to when a user navigates to the button with a keyboard?

Right now, if you navigate with the keyboard it will show the focus styling on the button. However, when I try to add the `'Mui-focusVisible'` class to the button, nothing happens. I checked the DOM and it shows the class was added, but it has no effect on the styling.

Current implementation:

I have a hook that gets the last actively clicked button:

```
const activeElement = useActiveInputElement();
```

I then have a useEffect that adds the focus class based on some conditions.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (lastFocusedElementId) {
      window.setTimeout(() => document.getElementById(lastFocusedElementId)?.focus(), 0);
    }
  }, []);
```

Here's the icon button

```
<IconButton
      id={props.id}
      sx={props.sx}
    >
      {icon}
    </IconButton>
```

When I console.log activeElement and lastFocusedElementId, I get the correct element but no styling changes are applied when I add the class. Any ideas?